# python 3: Dictionary, formating time

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to format the `durationdictionary` to get (hours:mins:seconds) for each unique element. There are 7 unique numbers in the the dictionary.

Below is a sample of the `durationdictionary`: Can someone please show me how to do this. (Format is `{Phonenumber : Total seconds}`)

```
{'7807890123': 129370, '7803214567': 179532, '7808907654': 121726, '7809876543': 190211}
```

Here's my code:

```
def call_list():
    list =[line.strip().split(";") for line in calls_file]

    #Gets the total amount of seconds for each unique user in the list.
    for i in list:
      duration = int(i[3]) 

      if i[1] in durationdictionary.keys():
             durationdictionary[i[1]] += duration
      else:
             durationdictionary[i[1]] = duration

    # Gets the total amount of seconds from each individual in the dictionary called durationdictionary at index 1 and converts in into the format (h:m:s)
    for i in list:
        min_t = math.floor(durationdictionary[i[1]]//60)
        second = math.floor(durationdictionary[i[1]]//60)
        minute = min_t//60
        hour = minute//60
        durationdictionary[i[1]] = str(hour) + "h" + str(minute) + "m" +  str(second) + "s"


        print(durationdictionary)
```

Comment: This is probably unrelated to your issue, but it's generally a bad idea to use the name of a global like `list` as a local variable. The local variable will shadow the builtin `list` type, which may cause unexpected errors if you try to use the builtin later.

Comment: Yes thank you. I'll have to change that.

Comment: What's wrong with your code?

Comment: Well it's not producing the output i want. I have tried several different things. But as it is right now, i'm gettting flagged with this error    (durationdictionary[i[1]] += duration TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly). Inaddition, i am most certain the way i'm trying to calculate the (hour:minute:seconds) is tottaly

Answer (score 1):

To break up your number of seconds into hours, minutes and seconds, I suggest using `divmod` repeatedly. Calling `divmod(a, b)` returns a 2-tuple, `(a//b, a%b)` (and it may be more efficient at calculating them than using both operators yourself):

```
minutes, seconds = divmod(durationdictionary[i[1]], 60)
hours, minutes = divmod(minutes, 60)
```

I think there's another issue though, since you're iterating over `list` to get `i`, but modifying `durationdictionary` in a way that can't be repeated (you're converting the values from integers to strings. You probably want to be iterating over the dictionary's `items()`, or maybe just building a new dictionary instead of modifying the values of the existing one.

Here's some code that updates `durrationdictionary` in place, using the above logic to convert the times:

```
for phone_number, seconds in durationdictionary.items():
    minutes, seconds = divmod(seconds, 60)
    hours, seconds = divmod(minutes, 60)
    durationdictionary[phone_number] = "{}h{}m{}s".format(hours, minutes, seconds)
```

Comment: I'm trying to format of each individuals time  back into the dictionary.  For example                                                                                                            
old dictionary : {Phonenumber : Total seconds} to updating that same dictioanry with: {phonenumber: (hour:mins:seconds)}

Comment: Okay, I'll give it a shot

Comment: How  would  you format them so that the minutes and seconds should have a prefix of 0 if less than 10? I tired durationdictionary[phone_number] = "{}h{02}m{02}s".format(hours, minutes, seconds). I saw this on another post doesnot work for me

Comment: You need a colon at the start of bit in the brackets: `"{:02}h{:02}m{:02}s"`. Without the colon, your padding and width are mistaken for an index into the arguments (`{2}` is the third argument).